# Debian freezes while intense SSD I/O

Tags: linux, debian, ssd, io

I bought an SSD drive (Kingston SSDNow) and installed Debian 8 on it;

The system works fine. But today I'm tried to extract a huge tar archive (~8GB) and in the middle of extraction the system just freezed, nothing happened at all and I restarted it. Then I tried again, and again it freezed; I moved the tar to HDD and there it was extracted correctly;

I this a SSD Hardware glitch? Or just something wrong in configuration?

Here is a SMART of my SSH

```
smartctl 6.4 2014-10-07 r4002 [x86_64-linux-3.16.0-4-amd64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-14, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     SandForce Driven SSDs
Device Model:     KINGSTON SV300S37A240G
Serial Number:    50026B72590BB1C7
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0026b7 2590bb1c7
Firmware Version: 603ABBF0
User Capacity:    240,057,409,536 bytes [240 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS, ACS-2 T13/2015-D revision 3
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Sat Dec 26 00:52:49 2015 GET
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (    0) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x7d) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    No Auto Offline data collection support.
                    Abort Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (  48) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x0025) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x0032   095   095   050    Old_age   Always       -       0/19384044
  5 Retired_Block_Count     0x0033   100   100   003    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours_and_Msec 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       28h+05m+26.610s
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       19
171 Program_Fail_Count      0x000a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
172 Erase_Fail_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
174 Unexpect_Power_Loss_Ct  0x0030   000   000   000    Old_age   Offline      -       1
177 Wear_Range_Delta        0x0000   000   000   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
181 Program_Fail_Count      0x000a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
182 Erase_Fail_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
189 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0000   020   032   000    Old_age   Offline      -       20 (Min/Max 6/32)
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   020   032   000    Old_age   Always       -       20 (Min/Max 6/32)
195 ECC_Uncorr_Error_Count  0x001c   120   120   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0/19384044
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0033   100   100   003    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
201 Unc_Soft_Read_Err_Rate  0x001c   120   120   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0/19384044
204 Soft_ECC_Correct_Rate   0x001c   120   120   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0/19384044
230 Life_Curve_Status       0x0013   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       100
231 SSD_Life_Left           0x0000   100   100   011    Old_age   Offline      -       4294967296
233 SandForce_Internal      0x0032   000   000   000    Old_age   Always       -       4294963473
234 SandForce_Internal      0x0032   000   000   000    Old_age   Always       -       67
241 Lifetime_Writes_GiB     0x0032   000   000   000    Old_age   Always       -       67
242 Lifetime_Reads_GiB      0x0032   000   000   000    Old_age   Always       -       37
244 Unknown_Attribute       0x0000   100   100   010    Old_age   Offline      -       1310737

SMART Error Log not supported

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Comment: Any error message  with `dmesg`? Also, did you check, at the time of the failure, what the use of your memory was? Did you use the swap? How large is your swap anyway?

Comment: I have 8GB of RAM and 2GB of swap; No that is not because of memory; I can't get any report from dmesg because of system hang.

Comment: The thing is I cant reproduce the error now, I maked trim (fstrim -a), and after that archive extracted successfully; But later I got I/O error in Thunar and a system crushed